# Use IF statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to use IF ELSE statement in a sql query because of legacy application that takes user input and run the same query. Depending on the user's input I need different results.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b
where a.user_id = b.user_id
AND IF
b.last_name = '' or b.last_name = NULL
THEN
a.user_id in (1, 2, 3) or a.user_name in ('John', 'Mark', 'Lucas')
ELSE
b.last_name = 'DOE'
```

Comment: First things first - don't use the old style join syntax, specify the join condition as in: FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.user_id = b.user_id.  Next - you don't need an if statement, just appropriately placed parentheses to 'group' each condition: AND (( (b.last_name = '' or b.last_name IS NULL) AND (a.user_id IN (1, 2, 3) OR a.user_name IN ('John', 'Mark', 'Lucas')) OR b.last_name = 'DOE')

Comment: @Jeff - are you familiar with the (non)support for empty string in Oracle SQL? It seems not; the empty string is the same as `null` in Oracle.

Comment: @mathguy - what does that have to do with this question?  Regardless - checking for column = NULL is bad practice and you should use IS NULL.  So what is your concern - that I changed it to IS NULL?  If so - why?

Comment: @jeff - `column = NULL` is not bad practice, it is simply wrong. But that isn't what you wrote; you wrote `column = ''` which (to me) suggests you weren't aware that `''` is the same as `NULL` (since you left it there, followed by `OR column IS NULL`).

Comment: @mathguy - I guess you should read the original question, which had this: b.last_name = '' or b.last_name = NULL.  So all I did was change the original from = NULL to IS NULL.  Of course, that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a PL/SQL statement; you cannot use it in SQL.

Just use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A a
       INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
       ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE  (   b.last_name IS NULL
       AND (  a.user_id in (1, 2, 3)
           OR a.user_name in ('John', 'Mark', 'Lucas')
       )
OR     b.last_name = 'DOE'
```

*Note: In Oracle, an empty string and `NULL` are identical.*